# Where is YouTube Channel ID input in BigQuery Data Transfer Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm working on GCP BigQuery. And I use BigQuery Data Transfer Service to get market data from YouTube, Goolge Ads, so on.

Yesterday, I found out that there is no input box of YouTube Channel Page Id in BigQuery Data Transfer Service. The YouTube channel page ID is needed to connect YouTube Channel.

Why does the channel page Id input box disappear?
I guess that Transfer Service account always should be equal to YouTube Channel account, So It doens't needed.

Anyway, I want to know why the input box disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Channel Page Id has recently been removed as this input is not necessary for anything related to loading reports/data. It is only used within YouTube data source for logging purpose.

Comment: can you please address"The YouTube channel page ID is needed to connect YouTube Channel." which is obviously the core reason for the question?!

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant No It's not core reason. I just wonder why **the** input box was removed.